# apache not connecting to .local domain

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have apache2 on my Mac OS X Lion box with name-based virtual hosting turned on.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.puter.edu
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/Sites"
    <Directory "/path/to/Sites">
    ...
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.local
    ProxyPass        / http://127.0.0.1:25012/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:25012/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName bar.local
    ProxyPass        / http://127.0.0.1:25013/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:25013/
</VirtualHost>
```

My `/etc/hosts` file has the following entries

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

127.0.0.1       foo.local
127.0.0.1       bar.local
184.72.115.86   search.yahoo.com
```

From the command line I can successfully `ping my.puter.edu`, `ping foo.local`, and `ping bar.local`. But from the browser I can only reach http://my.puter.edu. The browser is unable to establish a connection to foo.local and bar.local.

Suggestions?

Comment: [Don't abuse `local.`.  You don't own that domain name.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-use-domain-names-that-you-own.html)  As a MacOS 10 user, you should be even more aware of this than most people are.  It has been well-known in the Apple world for ten years.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the problem of proxy behind apache that you are using for foo.local and bar.local as per your configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.local
    ServerAlias bar.local
    ProxyPass        / http://127.0.0.1:25012/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:25012/
</VirtualHost>
```

What are running behind 25012 port (Are they actually running or not ?) ? Have you checked apache logs ? Browser error output can not match the verbosity of log files when debugging.

Comment: I am running Starman (a different web server) on ports 25012 and 25013. foo.local should be served from 25012 and bar.local from 25013.

Comment: can you see your page with http://foo.local:25012/ in your browser ?

Comment: no, because foo.local is not running on 25012. I can see http://127.0.0.1:25012 in the browser, but foo.local is supposed to resolve to http://127.0.0.1:25012 and that is not happening.

Comment: I don't know how configuration is laid out in starman ! But foo.local should resolve to 127.0.0.1 according to your hosts file ! what does apache logs say ?